# placing next button bottom of ConstraintLayout with viewport in scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I'm developing activity drawing view programmatically.
I wanna place 'NEXT' button to bottom of ConstraingLayout in scrollView
so, Adding ViewPort attribute in scrollView.
It's works for me. when there is no scroll.

But,
If ConstraintLayout's height is stretched, It isn't works correctly.

This is parent code using PageIndicatorView and ViewPager.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:attrs="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activities.AssetAddActivity">

<com.rd.PageIndicatorView
    android:id="@+id/pageIndicatorView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:piv_selectedColor="#79f56e02"
    app:piv_unselectedColor="#1ef56e02"
    app:piv_viewPager="@id/addAssetViewPager"
    attrs:piv_padding="12dp"
    attrs:piv_radius="8dp" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/addAssetViewPager"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[this is my fragment xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dR98e.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/scrollview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:paddingBottom="50dp">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"

        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_btn_login"
        android:text="@string/button_next"
        android:textColor="@color/colorButtonText"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/insert_point"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtv_beacon_info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="새로 등록할 대상의 분류\n그리고 ID와 이름을 입력해주세요."
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtv_title_category"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtv_title_category" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_asset_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Asset ID"
            android:inputType="text" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_asset_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Asset Name"
            android:inputType="text" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/insert_point"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textInputLayout4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textInputLayout4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout4" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtv_title_category"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:text="@string/txtv_category"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtv_beacon_info" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and this picture is problem screenshot.
[problem screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oghM6.png)

Comment: share your whole layout

Comment: @NileshRathod sorry, I added parent layout.